# Django logs out when dev server restarts

Tags: python, django

While developing a Django 1.8 project, I am logged out each time the dev server restarts. That means each time the python code is changed (and the dev server restarts) I have to log back in. It's driving me slightly crazy.

I am using the default `SESSION_ENGINE` i.e. `django.contrib.sessions.backends.db` and can see the `django_session` table has values.

I have `DEBUG=True` on.

Can anyone suggest other things to check? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As a security measure (so as to not save sensitive information in public version control) I was autogenerating the `SECRET_KEY` in `settings.py` e.g.

```
chars = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789!@#$%^&*(-_=+)'
SECRET_KEY = get_random_string(50, chars)
```

When the runserver reboots, this gets regenerated but because this is the session token, the one in the database doesn't match the one in settings and I have log in. Not a problem for deployed version but the cause of the pain in dev version.

To get around this I leave this line in `settings.py` and hard code a `SECRET_KEY` in `local_settings.py` which does not get committed to version control.

## Update 20 Oct 2022

I now use an environment variable e.g.

```py
import os
SECRET_KEY = os.environ['SECRET_KEY']
```

and would not recommend this solution. As mentioned by @abdul-aziz-barkat in the comments, when you have multiple processes serving a website you can get a condition where you users are constantly logged out.

Comment: You leave this line in your settings? That's not a great solution, what happens when you update the production server for instance? This doesn't even consider having multiple processes of the same application running at the same time, each then having a different secret key causing users to randomly log out on the load balancer's whims. Don't do this, just use environment variables...

Answer (score 0):

> That means each time the python code is changed (and the dev server restarts) I have to log back in.

Django automatically incorporates changes to python code *without* the need to manually restart the server. The server *will* need to be restarted if any new files have been added.

Are you migrating your changes in with `python manage.py migrate`?
Ensure that you are not using the `--noreload` option with `python manage.py runserver`.

See the [django-admin runserver docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-runserver). Hope this helps. (*and apologies for not having the ability to comment.*)

Comment: Thanks, but my problem is that Django logs out whether I restart the dev server manually or if it happens automatically.