# Django keeps logging me out from dev server when changing my codebase

Tags: django

In my Django app I have a lot of `if request.user.is_authenticated` logic and once I change some code other than in templates (like forms, models, views, etc.) I get logged out from the development server which makes it quite annoying to always have to re-login in the frontend to test my prior code changes again.

Is there any way to stay logged in (a superuser) when in `Debug = True` (or other) mode?

```
# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = os.getenv("DEBUG", "False") == "True"

# Add s.th. here to keep me logged in?
```

```
# settings.py

SECRET_KEY = os.getenv("DJANGO_SECRET_KEY", get_random_secret_key())

MIDDLEWARE = [
    "django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware",
]

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    "django.contrib.admin",
    "django.contrib.auth",
    "django.contrib.contenttypes",
    "django.contrib.sessions",
    
    ...
]
```

Comment: It has been a while since I used `django`. I belive this problem is because of `SESSION_ENGINE` setting. Dont remember how to fix it but it would be a good starting point for you to search about.

Comment: Are you using the Django database-backed sessions?

Comment: @JoVi I didnt set up any custom settings yet, so Im probably with the default

Comment: Have you configure the `SESSION_ENGINE` setting? Is the value of the `SECRET_KEY` setting constant or are you getting it dynamically somehow?

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat I didnt configure `SESSION_ENGINE`. My `SECRET_KEY` is `SECRET_KEY = os.getenv("DJANGO_SECRET_KEY", get_random_secret_key())`

Comment: Ah, there you go. That's your problem. The authentication partly depends on the secret key, if it is updated all logins will get invalidated. I'd close this as a duplicate of [Django logs out when dev server restarts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33249017/django-logs-out-when-dev-server-restarts) but you've put up a bounty which blocks close votes.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat ah nice, thanks. Hmm then just post an answer and I grant the bounty?

Comment: Nope, I've already found a duplicate :) I've raised a flag for the moderators to remove the bounty (You'll get refunded your reputation if that happens) and close the question as duplicate.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django logs out when dev server restarts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33249017/django-logs-out-when-dev-server-restarts)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is:

```
SECRET_KEY = os.getenv("DJANGO_SECRET_KEY", get_random_secret_key())
```

You are generating a new secret key every time the server is restarted. The authentication details are stored in `django_sessions` table, and the session details are hashed with the SECRET_KEY. So, every time the SECRET_KEY value is changed, the current session details are invalidated and you need to freshly login again.

For the solution:
Generate a random secret key manually once and store it as an environment variable in every environment (be it staging, production, or development).

Hope you find this useful.